# Choosing Intent for Zip files

Tags: android, android-intent, zip, android-intent-chooser

I have a zip file which was downloaded from url and its path is set to `/storage/emulated/0/myapp/downloadedfile.zip`

Now I would like to open this zip file via choose intent to list the available apps to open the downloaded file.

I have set this in manifest:

```
 <activity
      android:name=".MyApp"
      android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
      android:launchMode="singleInstance"
      android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/zip"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now I'm calling this way to open the intent chooser

```
File downloadedfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapp") + "/" + "downloadedfile.zip");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(downloadedfile), "application/zip");
startActivity(intent);
```

This works fine if I have **`ESFileExplorer`** has already installed on my app

But I would like to check if there is any pre-installed app is available or else I need to show **`playstore`** also as one of the option so that user can download the app and install the ESFileExplorer app.

So how do I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android Intent Zip File

```
try{
    File downloadedfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapp") + "/" + "downloadedfile.zip");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(downloadedfile), "application/zip");
    startActivity(intent);
}catch (ActivityNotFoundException Ae){
    //When No application can perform zip file
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=" + "application/zip");
    Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    try {
         startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
         //the device hasn't installed Google Play
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You don't have Google Play installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SID- This opens up the send intent

Comment: Check Updated Answer

Comment: @coder first it search for zip intent. if nothing found then it open playstore for application that support zip file.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch startActivity intent with ActivityNotFoundException and there you can launch ES File Explorer market app on play store.

Comment: Any comments or do you want me to write code for you?